# AttributeError: int object has no attribute append

Tags: python, tkinter, attributes, int, append

Everyone Im quite new in coding and Python .What I was trying to do in my program is to save every entry of "expenses_input" in an array which is "entries" so that later on I can print out every expenses_input in other def function. Anyone can please help and debug my program which facing the AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'.I wonder am i doing the right way ? Here is the code , Hope my question clear enough,I appreciate your help, Thank You.

```
def expenses(u,user,file,data_list,controller):
data_list = file["ext_data"]
u = data_list[user]
expenses=Tk()
entries=[]
for entries in range(10):
    expenses_label=tk.Label(expenses,text="RM: ").grid(row=1)
    expenses_input = tk.Entry(expenses).grid(row=1,column=1)
    entries.append(expenses_input)

    BSave=tk.Button(expenses,text="SAVE" ,command=lambda:u.__add_expenses__(expenses_input, categories_input,notes_input))
    BSave.grid(row=5)

    data_list[user] = u
    file["ext_data"] = data_list  
expenses.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

you're defining your list:

```
entries=[]
```

but after that you're reusing the variable for your range, which is of type `int`:

```
for entries in range(10):
```

if you just want to loop 10 times, just anonymize your variable:

```
for _ in range(10):
```

Comment: Hey bro mind i ask what should I do currently in order to fix that bug?Sorry about that i was quite new to coding life T_T